# QtCreator can't use G++ for cross compiling. Must be a configuration issue

Tags: qt-creator, qt5

When I try to compile a code for VAR SOM AM33 using QTCreator I get this error:

c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../buscaTexto -I. -I/opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5 -I/opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I/opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++ -o main.o ../buscaTexto/main.cpp

make: c: Command not found

QTCreator's qmake generates a Makefile including this:

$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o main.o ../buscaTexto/main.cpp

And $(CXX) is defined as following:

CXX           = $(OE_QMAKE_CXX)

I know this is wrong because when I compile this code for PC I haven't any error and the Makefile define CXX as following:

CXX           = g++

So It runs:

g++ c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../buscaTexto -I. -I/opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5 -I/opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I/opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++ -o main.o ../buscaTexto/main.cpp

The value of OE_QMAKE_CXX is defined in the file /opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/i686-arago-linux/environment-setup.d/qt5.sh as following:

export OE_QMAKE_CXX=$CXX

Makefile's header includes this:

# Command: /opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/i686-arago-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -spec linux-oe-g++ CONFIG+=debug -o Makefile ../buscaTexto/buscaTexto.pro

the file /opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++/qmake.conf defines:
QMAKE_CXX      = $(OE_QMAKE_CXX)

but the file /opt/qt5devtools/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++/qmake.conf defines:
QMAKE_CXX               = arm-linux-gnueabi-g++

I don't know why QtCreator uses linux-oe-g++ because I have configured all for using linux-arm-gnueabi-g++.

Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue. The solution is here:
http://wiki.wandboard.org/index.php/Setup_QT_creator_for_developing_QT_apps_on_wandboard